# Can someone help me add a line counter to my code when I read this file

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to add a line counter because if I do a while statement such as

```
while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
    lines+=1;
    file.nextLine();
}
```

then the rest of my vowels, sentences, etc are set to 0.

my code is:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System. in );
System.out.println("Enter file name: ");

File file = new File(input.nextLine());

if (file.length() == 0) {
    System.out.println("The input file is empty.");
    System.exit(1);
}

Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
    String word = fileReader.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') vowels += 1;
        if ((ch == '!' || ch == '.' || ch == '?')) sentences += 1;
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) alphaNumeric += 1;
        switch (ch) {
            case ',':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '[':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case ']':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case ':':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '`':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '-':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '!':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '_':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '(':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case ')':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '.':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '?':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case '"':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;
            case ';':
                punctuation += 1;
                break;

        }
    }
    words += 1;

}
System.out.println("The number of words in the file name: " + words);
System.out.println("The number of lines in the file name: " + lines);
System.out.println("The number of alphanumeric characters " + "in the file name: " + alphaNumeric);
System.out.println("The number of sentences in the file name: " + sentences);
System.out.println("The number of vowels in the file name: " + vowels);
System.out.println("The number of punctuations in the file name: " + punctuation);
```

Comment: Some objection to LineNumberReader?

Comment: You could use `nextLine` over `next`.  This would require you to parse `String`, but would make it easier to count the lines - IMHO

Comment: You `case` statements can be combined to: `switch (ch) { case ',': case '[': case ']': /** more symbols **/ punctuation += 1; break; }`

Comment: And you could replace `vowel += 1` into `++vowel` or `vowel++` for brevity.

Comment: move this condition: `if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch))` to the top since letters are also alphanumerics and you can save some checkings. Also the punctuation switch into an `else` after this condition.

Answer (score 1):

Newlines are denoted by the character '\n'. You could check for instances of that, the same way you are checking for vowels, punctuation, etc.

Comment: im still confused because my loop only accounts for words not spaces or \n

Answer (score 0):

Use these set of lines

```
   String line = fileReader.nextLine();

   for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
                 char ch = line.charAt(i);
                 if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') vowels += 1;
                 if ((ch == '!' || ch == '.' || ch == '?')) sentences += 1;
                 if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) alphaNumeric += 1;
                 switch (ch) {
                    // do something

                 }
             }
             lines ++;
             words += line.split(" ").length;
```

In your original code, the words were nothing but lines. They were not words as such.